# Is it possible to convert the animated GIF to SVG?

Tags: svg, frontend, gif, animated-gif, svg-animate

Everyone!
I hope you are doing well.
I have a gif file that will be used for the background of my homepage.
But its resolution is not good so I think it would be better if I use the GIF as SVG.
Is there any way to convert the GIF image to SVG.
Any tools or website link will be helpful for me.
Thanks.

Comment: No it isn't possible. GIF is a raster format but SVG is vector.